# Unable to build with Angular 12 / 13

Tags: angular, getstream-io

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on Angular [provided here](https://getstream.io/chat/angular/tutorial/#build-a-basic-chat-app-with-streams-core-angular-components). I'm unable to build StreamChatModule since `ngx-popper` and `angular-mentions` seems to require Angular > 14.

I've installed with the option `--legacy-peer-deps` since we use Angular 12.

Weird thing is when I go to my package-lock it's tell that the angular-mention installation require only Angular > 7 like below:

```json
 "node_modules/angular-mentions": {
      "version": "1.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/angular-mentions/-/angular-mentions-1.5.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-6l63v7AvrX9vFzj2h7jAPTnQ390IomCz3HiQP+b3PnDvaZiycd+tiVavi5RxAIX8WYjsamAR+tTPCkOkBkqZ+w==",
      "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": ">=7.2.0",
        "@angular/core": ">=7.2.0"
      }
    },
```

However popperjs require Angular 14:

```json
"node_modules/ngx-popperjs": {
      "version": "14.1.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-popperjs/-/ngx-popperjs-14.1.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FL+IKYydZIcqOGgjrVb9iBAzG7MTGF3zS7JeMF5CmAVXXI6p2IeDf2SEHyT1SghzMW9yy23EHfpYEaowtrMiBg==",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^14.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "^14.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^7.4.0"
      }
    },
```

This is the full error from angular-mention:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string '/Users/jbardon/code/petalmd.web/node_modules/angular-mentions/fesm2015/angular-mentions.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.6, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.
  425 | }
  426 | MentionListComponent.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "14.0.6", ngImport: i0, type: MentionListComponent, deps: [{ token: i0.ElementRef }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Component });
> 427 | MentionListComponent.ɵcmp = i0.ɵɵngDeclareComponent({ minVersion: "14.0.0", version: "14.0.6", type: MentionListComponent, selector: "mention-list", inputs: { labelKey: "labelKey", itemTemplate: "itemTemplate" }, outputs: { itemClick: "itemClick" }, viewQueries: [{ propertyName: "list", first: true, predicate: ["list"], descendants: true, static: true }, { propertyName: "defaultItemTemplate", first: true, predicate: ["defaultItemTemplate"], descendants: true, static: true }], ngImport: i0, template: `
      |                             ^
  428 |     <ng-template #defaultItemTemplate let-item="item">
  429 |       {{item[labelKey]}}
  430 |     </ng-template>'
```

From what I see is that a component from angular-mention required Angular 14+

Did you have an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Upgrade your angular. 12 is no longer supported. `npx npm-check-updates`

Comment: Upgraded on 13, still the same issue.

Comment: I would delete both node_modules and package-lock, and do fresh npm install if you have upgraded to angular 13

Comment: If "ngx-popper and angular-mentions seems to require Angular > 14." then of course only upgrading to 13 won't solve your issue... (◔_◔)

Comment: Yes. That just surprise me that a library have no retro-compatibility for a version of angular released one year ago. So problem solved by upgrading to 14. Second thing is that the documentation (of Getstream) explicitly say that it's compatible with Angular 12 but it didn't really. That's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from the `stream-chat-angular` developer team, and the SDK does support Angular@12. Unfortunately, the install command in the tutorial was wrong. Please try this one (tested with npm v7):

```
npm install stream-chat-angular stream-chat @ngx-translate/core angular-mentions@1.4.0 ngx-popperjs@12 --legacy-peer-deps
```

We have an open ticket to fix this, which also gives some context about the problem: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-angular/issues/410.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hey Zita ! Thank you very much, missed the issue on the repo :) Is the features provided by Stream chat are still usable with these versions ? Anyway I think we plan to upgrade to 14 is the near future, so it's ok!

Comment: The issue was created after your question :). Yes, this uses the latest version of stream-chat-angular with all available features.

Comment: Thanks Zita.  I was checking the repository at https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-angular/ there the app version is angular 12, and voilà , those components are set to version "ngx-popperjs": "^12.2.1", and "angular-mentions": "^1.4.0"